# how to add email,saudi mobile and national ID validation in cshtml?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i want to add validations to this fields: email , mobile number ( the length is 10 numbers and starts with 05 ) and National ID ( the length is 10 numbers and starts with 1 or 2 )

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtNID" name="NID">

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtMobile" name="mobileNumber">

<input class="form-control" type="email" id="txtEmail" name="email" >

<input type="button" id="btnSend" class="btn btn-view" value="send" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For UI validation you can use attributes of input tag, like 'minlength', 'maxlength' and 'pattern':

```
<form>
    <input class="form-control" pattern="05.*" minlength="10" maxlength="10"  type="text" id="txtNID" name="NID">
    <input class="form-control" pattern="[12].*" minlength="10" maxlength="10"  type="text" id="txtMobile" name="mobileNumber">
    <input class="form-control" type="email" id="txtEmail" name="email" >
    <input type="submit" id="btnSend" class="btn btn-view" value="send" />
</form>
```

Also you need to add server side validations.

You can read more about input tag attributes here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp